# expo-modules-core/gradle.groovy' as it does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was trying to build my expo app I keep geeting this error

```
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating settings 'ClickNApp'.
[stderr] > Could not read script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/gradle.groovy' as it does not exist.
```

this are my deps in the package.json file

```js
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.16.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.46.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.13.1",
    "expo": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.38",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-shimmer": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-virtualized-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2"
}
```

I tried pretty my much everything and I kept getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and run "expo doctor".

It seems your package versions are misaligned. Also you have "expo:1.0.0" should probably be an error in your package.json.

Try and use a supported version instead.
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/